# Conditional second moment normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, moment-problem

Can someone help me find the expression of

$$
E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) \quad when \quad  Z\sim N(0,1)
$$

I'm aware that
$$
E(Z | Z \leq 0) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \quad , \,\, Z \sim N(0,1)
$$
using the Inverse Mills Ratio, but I don't know how to apply it to the second moment.

Comment: This helped me a lot https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/expected-value-of-x-in-a-normal-distribution-given-that-it-is-below-a-certain-v

Comment: Try $E[Z^2\mid Z\le 0]=Var[Z\mid Z\le 0]+(E[Z\mid Z\le 0])^2$, or directly $E[Z^2\mid Z\le 0]=\frac1{P(Z\le 0)}E[Z^21_{Z\le 0}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this method work?
\begin{align*}
E(Z^2) &= E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) \mathbb P(Z\leq 0)+E(Z^2 | Z \geq 0) \mathbb P(Z\geq 0)\\
&= E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) \frac{1}{2}+E(Z^2 | Z \geq 0) \frac{1}{2}\\
&= E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) \frac{1}{2}+E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) \frac{1}{2}\\
&= E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) 
\end{align*}
where the first equality is by iterated expectation (total probability), the second equality is by property of $\mathcal N (0,1)$, the third equality is by symmetry of Z around 0.

But $E(Z^2) = 1 +(E[Z])^2 =1$. So $E(Z^2 | Z \leq 0) =1$

Comment: Seems about right, yes. Thank you!